# What is the conventional interpretation of the subscript $\alpha$ in the sequence $\{B_{\alpha}\}$?

Tags: measure-theory, notation

I am taking a graduate level measure theory class, and I have a question that is decidedly *undergraduate* in difficulty. I have asked myself (and others) this question in other classes and other contexts, and I have neither discovered nor been given an answer that is sufficiently satisfactory. But I am working on understanding a proof from *Real Analysis for Graduate Students* by Bass, and this question seems to be impossible to ignore given its relationship to the larger proof I am trying to understand. With that said, here's the question.

Given a sequence of open balls $\{B_{\alpha}\}$, what is the intended meaning of the variable $\alpha$? *-Is it the cardinality of balls in the sequence?* *-Is it any such ball in the sequence?* *-Both? -Neither?* Clearly, I am clueless as to how $\alpha$ is intended to be used, and the context seems to offer no hints pointing to the author's intent. Is there perhaps a generally accepted convention of understanding?

Thanks in advance to all the insight(s) provided by the respondents.
Best

Answer (score 0):

Formally, a sequence $\{B_\alpha\}$ is a function from an index set $\mathcal I$ to the set of all open balls $\mathcal B$, i.e. $f\colon \mathcal I\to \mathcal B$. Then $\alpha\in\mathcal I$ denotes a generic element of $\mathcal I$, and $B_\alpha$ is a way of writing $f(\alpha)$ without mentioning the function $f$. The set $\mathcal I$ is allowed to be uncountable.

Comment: Thanks for such a swift response! So then if I want to speak of the 'last ball' or the least upper bound of such a sequence, I am forced to write $\sup_{\alpha} \{B_{\alpha}\}$, correct?

Comment: Yes that would make sense assuming you have defined some partial order on the set $\mathcal B$ of all open balls. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Formal_definition for the definition of supremum in an arbitrary poset (partially ordered set) of which $\mathcal B$ can be an example.